# An argument against a creation ex nihilo

Tags: logic

I wanna know the crucial points in this argument that just came to my mind to prove that nothing can come from nothing is logically true.

1. We define nothingness as the absence of anything bar logical laws (logical necessities).
2. From 1. follows that in a state of nothingness for any x it holds that x is not possible which is equivalent to the necessity of ~x which proves that a creation ex nihilo is impossible. (Note that x is just a variable ranging over any thing bar logical laws).

Comment: I'm out of turnips. That doesn't prove that it's not possible for me to have turnips. Likewise it does not follow that a state of nothingness for some x, like turnips, that turnips are not possible. It only means that I have to make a run to the turnip store. If I happen to want turnips. That is, the absence of x does not mean that ~x is necessary. It just means I ran out of x.

Comment: Logic cannot determine *creation ex nihilo* metaphysics. St. Thomas pointed out that every agent that effects something out of something presupposes the existence of the latter. Hence, if God always acted on something in producing his effects, then it would follow that what he presupposes in acting would not be created by him. But this would conflict with the earlier conclusion that God, as Unparticipated Esse, is the source of esse for all other things...

Comment: This is about my argument. Does 2. follow from 1. and if not then why?

Comment: If nothing can come from nothing is objectively true then how does reality as we know it exists? The only thing you allow is logical laws which ought to have reasons for existing as well. There are no exceptions in objective knowledge. An exception is a solid counter example. You define nothingness in a way that is impossible to start with. Even science does this kind of error. Where did particles come from to form the universe? What exactly exploded? If nothing was there all along there would be no explosion. If something is existing before the explosion why not a God? Similar arguments here.

Comment: You can certainly have your definition 1 in the spirit of a predicate normal modal logic system of possible worlds absent of any non-theorem propositions, then all you have are just tautologies and theorems like in a Platonic heaven. However, this doesn't sound like your goal. If Tegmark's MUH is true, then you'll be dismayed about your logic "derivation" after some contemplation...

Comment: If we want to mimick [Modal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/), your second step **∼◊A → □∼A** is correct; what is wrong is the first step:  **∼A → ∼◊A**.

Comment: @Pippen "*We define nothingness as the absence of anything bar logical laws*" No, we don't. Maybe you do but I don't. Nothingness is defined as the logical case where everything is non-existent, including logic and whatever.

Comment: @Pippen 1. "*From 1. follows that in a state of nothingness for any x it holds that x is not possible*" No, it doesn't follow at all. - 2. "*x is not possible which is equivalent to the necessity of ~x*" No, it is not equivalent. "~x" means "not x", which implies that x is a sentence, a statement, a proposition, not a thing in the world.

Comment: @Pippen "*which proves that a creation ex nihilo is impossible*" No, it doesn't. You certainly haven't demonstrated any such.

Comment: TIL the universe came from a turnip :-)

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA: ~x ranges over anything except logic which we need to form an argument at all, so x also ranges over possible states, therefore ~ x -> ~ possible x. The step from ~ possible x -> necessary ~x is justified bc it comes from a logical (equivalence) law which we can apply.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues: first you are not offering an argument, but an assertion, which might serve as a premise of an argument. There is no chain of reasoning here, just that you assert that if nothing exists then nothing can come from it.

Second, this assertion is not logical but metaphysical. A basic assertion of logic (a law of logic) is such that one cannot conceive that it might be otherwise. For example, "everything is equal to itself". There is no way to come up with a story where something is not equal to itself without twisting the meanings of the words involved. Another way to say this is that basic assertions of logic have the character of being definitional. "Everything is equal to itself" can be taken as part of the definition of "equal".

Your assertion does not have this character. I can conceive of something coming to exist from nothing. It may seem very implausible; I may not be able to imagine a mechanism or a reason why it would happen, but I can easily imagine nothing existing and then (pop!) a planet is floating in space. That's what makes your assertion metaphysical. It relies on my intuition of how things work, of the nature of reality rather than on what is conceivable.

Also note that you can't use your assertion as a sort of definition of "nothing". Suppose you were to define "nothing" as that from which no something can be created. This would raise all kinds of questions. Is this "nothing" different from simply a state in which no something exists? How is it different?

Comment: "*You keep me searching for the Heart of Gold...*"

Comment: I do argue. I give a definition and check what follows logically. I define nothingness = ~x except logic (it‘s a simplified version because x stands for propositions and objects, but I think it is sufficient for my point). From there follows logically that no x can be possible because possibility is a state you can negate and it is outside of logical laws we need to build an argument at all. I think we all agree that possibility is not nothing. From there it is easy bc if x is not possible then by pure modal logic it follows that ~x is necessary.

Comment: @pippen, first, a definition followed by an assertion is not an argument. An argument requires at least two assertions. Second, you seem to be ignoring the distinction I drew between logic and metaphysics. I'm not going to argue with you, just say that practically no one in the analytic tradition of philosophy would agree that your assertion is a matter of logic. Third, you are mistaken about possibility. It is highly controversial whether possibilities exist.